# python numba list of list of tuples

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to speed up my algorithm with numba, after no further improvements where left by using numpy and optimizing.

I have a function that does some computations in a large 2-fold nested loop:

```
import random
from numba import njit

@njit()
def decide_if_vaild():
    return bool(random.getrandbits(1))

@njit()
def decide_what_bin(bins):
    return random.randint(0, bins-1)

@njit()
def foo(bins, loops):
    results = [[] for _ in range(bins)]

    for i in range(loops):
        for j in range(i+1, loops):
            happy = decide_if_vaild()
            bin = decide_what_bin(bins)
            if happy:
                results[bin].append( (i,j) )
                # or
                # results[bin].append( [i,j] )
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = foo(3,100)
```

If I run this minimal example above I (as expected) get a typing error:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numba\typeinfer.py", line 104, in getone
    assert self.type is not None
numba.errors.InternalError: 
[1] During: typing of call at C:/Users/xxx/minimal_example.py (21)
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------

File "minimal_example.py", line 21
```

The problem is the: "results[bin].append( (i,j) )" where I try to add a tuple (does not work with lists either) to the list.

The number of bins is kown in advance, but how many elements (2-tuple or list or np.array) depends on how often decide_if_vaild evaluates to True, and as I don't know how often this will be and the computation is quite expensive I don't know any other workaround.

Any good ideas how I could generate the result in the jitted function and return it, or pass a global container that this function could fill?

This probably falls back to:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
list(list(list(int64))): unsupported nested memory-managed object
```

where a similiar issue for list(list(int64)) (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2560) was resolved in numba 0.39.0 as of https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/2840

Comment: This code can easily be rewritten with numpy using no for loops. Furthermore with `results = [[] for _ in range(bins)]` you are creating an empty and untyped list. Numba does not like this. And last but not least you should not overwrite internals such as `bin`.

Comment: @Scotty1- How can this be rewritten with numpy? Afaik numpy is not too happy working with dynamic sized vectors. As I dont know the size of the result bins bevor... Regarding the internal `bin`, this only happend to quickly show a reproducable minimal example.

Comment: I don't really know what variable `size` is, furthermore in your example `foo` only receives one argument. Thus I can't run your code to test it. But you could get happy with `happy = np.random.randint(0, 2, size, dtype=np.bool)` and then create results depending on the size of `happy`. Just try to "rethink" your code. It takes some time at the beginning but once you get used to vectorized code, you'll see it is much easier to read and understand (and faster and much more efficient...).

Comment: You are completely right, I'm sorry. I've corrected the example. I see what you mean, I'll give it a tought and a try, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have now implemented following workaround, even though it does not answer the question completly, it might be a suitable approach for others struggeling with this issue:

```
@njit()
def foo(bins, loops):
    results = []
    mapping = []

    for i in range(loops):
        for j in range(loops+1, size):
            happy = decide_if_vaild()
            bin = decide_what_bin(bins)
            if happy:
                results.append( (i,j) )
                mapping.append( bin )
    return results, mapping
```

This will return a list of tuples (supported as of numba 0.39.0) and a list of mappings, where mapping[i] contains the bin for results[i]. Now the jit-compiler works smoothly and I can unpack the results outside of jit.